# Unable to SSH into EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

I've read through the existing answers to this topic, but I still can't seem to connect. I've created an AWS key and saved to my ~/.ssh folder.

The command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/jdrake.pem ec2-user@ec2-75-101-217-120.compute-1.amazonaws.com -v
```

results in:

```
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ec2-75-101-217-120.compute-1.amazonaws.com [75.101.217.120] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/jdrake/.ssh/jdrake.pem type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ec2-75-101-217-120.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/jdrake/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/jdrake/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jdrake/.ssh/jdrake.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've also tried different users (ubuntu, root, jdrake) without success. I am on OSX.

Comment: You may have better luck getting help with this on the Amazon EC2 forum... or on ServerFault...

Comment: I gave up and tried a different image. That worked. It must have been the username, even though I tried a bunch.

Comment: Can you close and/or delete the question please ? If you close it, you can probably reply to the question and mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Closing this because it was 3 years ago and I don't remember the final solution.

Comment: o_O You know, you could have just accepted the answer of the dude who was honestly trying to help. Just saying...

Comment: I'm definitely grateful for the answer (thanks @jas_raj!), but my question includes "I've also tried different users (**ubuntu**, root, jdrake) without success".

Answer (score 0):

From the logs above you are connecting to an Ubuntu machine:

```
   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
```

Therefore the default username for that box will be `ubuntu`, not `ec2-user` which is only for Amazon Linux.

Comment: Cool. Please note that the question was asked years ago, so the server has likely been decomissioned by now. Thanks for the effort, anyway :-)

Comment: Ah good point - I'll be more careful to check the date first! Thanks